# Cant get answer_id into answers_results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

Ive got 3 models. Question, Answer and Result.

Got a middle model answers_results with an answer_id and a result_id.

The questions and answers are already in the database, so when someone starts a new survey it needs to save a result_id and answer_id in the answers_results table.

This is how my html looks like:

```
<input id="answer_id_5" name="answer_id[5]" type="checkbox" value="5">
```

This is how my answer model looks like:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :question_id, :value

  belongs_to :question

  has_and_belongs_to_many :results, :join_table => :answers_results
end
```

and here is my Result model:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :animal_id

  has_and_belongs_to_many :answers, :join_table => :answers_results
end
```

Result controller:

```
class ResultsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @result = Result.new
    @animal = Animal.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @result = Result.new(params[:result])
        if @result.save
            redirect_to @result
        else
            render 'new'
        end
  end

  def show
    @result = Result.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

But it doesnt save the answer_id to the answers_results.
It does save the result_id.

So my question is: How do I save the answer_id to the answers_results table.

Thanks,,

Comment: Could you post the relevant controller code as well?

Comment: Added the result controller!

Comment: you do not use answer in your controller create action at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thinks you have to use build method to store the answer_id directly in answer_results

Try the following approach

Get the answer with answer id and build result from that answer like below

```
def new
  answer = Answer.find(params[:answer_id])
  @result = answer.build_result # or anser.results.build
  #this is based on has_one/has_many relationship between answer and results
end

def create 
 @result = Result.new(params[:result])
 if @result.save
   redirect_to results_path
 else
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. He cant find the Answer.find(params[:answer_id]). So i changed that to Answer.find(params[:id]). But that's not working.

Comment: @KoopOtten are you passing answer_id as id to new/create action? If not passing pass it

Comment: I tried to pass answer_id in to new action, but that doesnt work. It says 'could not find Answer without ID'.